# Gridworld Removing Color from Actor

Tags: gridworld

I'm using Gridworld in my AP class and I'm trying to figure out how to completely remove the color from actors. If you don't set a color it defaults to RED, and neither me or my teacher know how to set the color to nothing. I've tried creating a new color that's transparent, but it didn't work.

Sorry if this is a nooby question, but we really can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(critter name).setColor(null);
that should do it

ex.

Critter henry=new Critter();
henry.setColor(null);